# How to search for queries where you require distinct values from subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know how to write a subquery that filters by eliminating all duplicate values completely.

I am trying to find out which courses have lectures in distinct rooms. I am unsure about how to write a subquery where I want to find courses with no duplicate rooms. For the diagram below, course 1235 has 7 lectures as it appears 7 times in course column, however I do not want to select 1235 because there are duplicate rooms for lectures (447 and 972). In my query, I do want to select course 1236 because all the rooms are different.

My attempt is:
(The relation/table name is called classes)

select classes.course from classes where classes.room in (select distinct classes.room from classes)

[image: relation table diagram]

Comment: This is a relational division problem. Please gives us the DDL of the table and INSERTs statement to reproduce your data to help you...

Comment: Hi SQL pro, I am sorry but I'm not sure if I know how to do that as this is not my database, but an example. Can you provide a generic answer, or tell me where I can find an answer?

Comment: I think you can use `group by` and `having` to get the disitinct 
example; 

SELECT course
FROM classes
GROUP BY course
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT room) = COUNT(room);
`

Comment: ...which is a form of relational division !